# window.opener.location.href | Fortify scan false positivee

Tags: javascript, security, asp-classic, fortify

I am using below javascript code in web page which has been raised as security vulnerability (Insecure Interaction CWE ID 079) by fortify analysis scan.

I believe this is false positive. Could you please confirm if this is false positive with detailed explanation

```
function reloadParentAndClose()
{
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href
window.close
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is flagged because setting `window.opener.location.href` from an insecure source may lead to open redirection or a similar vulnerability. And at the same time, `window.opener.location.href` is technically user input, and as such, insecure from a scanner's perspective. :)

So yes, I think this is a false positive. But is there no simpler way to reload the parent? :) I'm not such a Javascript guru, but maybe `window.opener.location.reload()`?

Another thing that comes to mind is you could potentially navigate the parent window even if there is already something else there - but I think this is a browser concern, it should not be possible to reload or navigate it if the user already navigated away.